# Nested composite view, display an element and edit an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, nested-attributes

Nested forms are great to edit attributes but here is another kind af nested form.

The Cart element has one address. Address belongs to cart.

In the show cart page i want to display a form to create the address.

In the cart controller show method there is an address created :

> @cartshowed.build_address

I tried to call :

```
<%= render :partial => "addresses/form" %>
```

or

```
<%= render :partial => "addresses/form", :locals => { @cartshowed.address => @address } %>
```

Neither of those solution work, how can i display an element and edit/create an attribute in the same page?